# Is it possible to Query a Query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, entity-framework-4

im struggling with Many to Many grouping for a order site im creating.

Currently my data comes out as this

```
IS0001; 20/11/2013 00:00:00; 

           | HP DL360p  | Samsung 840 Pro 256GB | HP DL360p Samsung 840 | Pro 256GB  | HP DL360p | Samsung 840 Pro 256GB | Total 
ITSupplier | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total? 
ITSupplier | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total? 
ITComms    | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total? 
ITComms    | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total? 
ITSol      | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total? 
ITSol      | 1132 | 477 | 1160 | 510 | 1135 | 160 | Total?
```

what i want is this

```
IS0001 20/11/2013

           | HP DL360p  | Samsung 840 Pro 256GB | Total 
ITSupplier | 1132       | 477                   | 1609
ITComms    | 1160       | 510                   | 1670
ITSol      | 1135       | 160                   | 1295
```

Heres my current query

```
var tblQuoting = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Select(qis => qis.QuoteID).Distinct();
var model = new List<QuoteViewModel>();
foreach (var Quotes in tblQuoting)
{
    var ModelItem = new QuoteViewModel
    {
        Quote = db.Quotes.Where(q => q.ID == Quotes).ToList(),
        Items = db.Quotes_Items_Suppliers.Include(t => t.tblItems).Include(t => t.tblSuppliers).Where(i => i.QuoteID == Quotes).ToList()
    };
    model.Add(ModelItem);
}
```

To get the result i need to group the suppliers and the items. I thought that if i could query the query i could group the item ids then group the supplier ids. but im not sure if or how to begin querying a query, is it possible?

my table structure is as follows:-

```
tblQuotes
ID | QuoteNo | Date

tblItems
ID | Itemname | Part No

tblSuppliers
ID | SupplierName | TelNo

tblQuotes_Items_Suppliers
ID | QuoteID | ItemID | SupplierID | Quantity | Price
```

Thanks for any help, im really struggling with this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var result = dbQuoteItemsSuppliers
            .Include(tbl => tbl.Item)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.Quote)
            .Include(tbl => tbl.Supplier).GroupBy(tbl => new { tbl.Quote, tbl.Supplier, tbl.Item })
            .Select(grouped => new QuoteItemSuppliers
                {
                    Quote = grouped.Key.Quote,
                    Supplier = grouped.Key.Supplier,
                    Item = grouped.Key.Item,
                    Quantity = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Quantity),
                    Price = grouped.Sum(tbl => tbl.Price)
                });
```

The result is quantity of ***Items***, by specific ***Supplier***, by specific ***Quota***, but without total for each supplier. You can easily do math from this.

Example of enumerating trough rows for each distinct quota:

```
foreach (var quoteId in dbQuotes.Select(quote => quote.Id).Distinct())
        {
            int id = quoteId;
            foreach (var row in result.Where(row => row.Quote.Id == id))
            {
                // here you got only rows for specific Quota
            }
        }
```

Oh, and here are my models I was working on:

```
public class Quote
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuoteNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNo { get; set; }
}
public class Supplier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TelNo { get; set; }
}

public class QuoteItemSuppliers
{
    public Quote Quote { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do I get the results into the model?

Comment: You can create a new class which will contain result row information.
Then u can modify the last select statement to return objects of this class.
Then add this result to model as List<yourNewResultClass> or IEnumerable

Comment: I dont understand what you mean, im quite new to this, could you show me it filling the class you made? my class is identical

Comment: I edited first code block. Now u have list of objects of known type.
You just need to calculate the totals.

Comment: Cannot convert itapp.models.tblquotes to itapp.model.quote? do you need to see my code for table names etc?

Comment: Those information I posted should be enough to solve your problem.
I won't code it for you more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43573/discussion-between-alexw-and-mbudnik)

Comment: Hi There, I haven't made any progress towards this, i dont have the knowledge to understand how to make it work, is there any chance you could show me so i can learn? Thanks